# События js, динамические элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перемещаю *div* при помощи js в разные места (`переменная` > `remove()` > `append()`), есть клик события на внутренние элементы. При изменении положения дива клик перестает работать, внутренние элементы при этом не меняют класс, на который повешено событие, — как это исправить?

[Пример на jsFF](https://jsfiddle.net/bufuhax7/)

```
$(".remove").click(function (){
    var removeBox = $(".holder");
    $(".holder").remove();
    $(".parent2").append(removeBox);
});


$(".holder > div").click(function () {
    console.log("Клик");
});
```

Comment: как минимум нужно добавить [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy Исправлено

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно справке по функции [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/):

> all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.'

> все привязанные обработчики и данные ассоциированные с элементами будут удалены. Для удаления элементов без удаления данных и обработчиков используйте [`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

---

```js
$(".remove").click(function() {
  var removeBox = $(".holder").detach();
  $(".parent2").append(removeBox);
});


$(".holder > div").click(function() {
  console.log("Клик");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="elem1">
      1111
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="parent2">

</div>
<button class="remove">переместить</button>
```

Comment: Взял на заметку , полезный метод

Answer (score 3):

удалив элемент, вы так же удаляете его событие. Повесьте событие на родителя через [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), родитель у вас не удаляется и событие для элементов внутри него будут работать.

```js
$(".remove").click(function (){
  var removeBox = $(".holder");
  $(".holder").remove();
  $(".parent2").append(removeBox);
});


$(".parent, .parent2").on('click', ".holder > div", function () {
  console.log("Клик");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="elem1">
      1111
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  
</div>
<button class="remove">переместить</button>
```